# nexmo voice API stream call using either Ruby or PhpHi ANyone

Tags: php, ruby, vonage

Anyone has used Nexmo voice API to create a Stream an audio file to an active call
https://developer.nexmo.com/api/voice#stream-an-audio-file-to-an-active-call

Any example source code using php or ruby or any other languages?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a look at the ruby gem?

https://github.com/Nexmo/nexmo-ruby

Comment: May I know what does the answer_url referring to?

Answer (score 0):

The README for the Nexmo Ruby gem has a code sample for [streaming audio to a call.](https://github.com/Nexmo/nexmo-ruby#stream-audio-to-a-call)

```
require 'nexmo'

client = Nexmo::Client.new(api_key: 'YOUR-API-KEY', api_secret: 'YOUR-API-SECRET')

response = client.calls.create({
  to: [{type: 'phone', number: 'TO-NUMBER'}],
  from: {type: 'phone', number: 'FROM-NUMBER'},
  answer_url: ['https://example.com/answer']
})

stream_url = 'https://nexmo-community.github.io/ncco-examples/assets/voice_api_audio_streaming.mp3'

response = client.stream.start("CALL-UUID", stream_url: stream_url)
```